# duvida com select e angular Js

Tags: angularjs, select

estou usando o [selectize](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) e angularJs, o meu selectize esta configurado assim:

no controller

```
//configurando o select mrdicamento
$scope.selectize_medicamento = {
    plugins: {
        'remove_button': {
            label: ''
        }
    },
    maxItems: 1,
    valueField: 't0051_id_medicamento',
    labelField: 't0051_nome',
    searchField: 't0051_alldata',
    placeholder: "Medicamanto",
    create: false,

};
$scope.objMedicamento = { "selectedMedicamento ": null };
$scope.selectedMedicamento = [];
$scope.itemsMedicamento = [];
```

na view

```
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
   <label>Fornecedor</label>
     <selectize id="selectize_medicamento" required config="selectize_mediacmento" options="itemsMedicamento" position="bottom" ng-model="objMedicamento.selectedMedicamento"></selectize>
```

para obter o valueField:

```
 var id_med = $scope.objMedicamento.selectedMedicamento;
```

porem eu preciso obter tambem o labelFiel, ou seja, o texto que esta no seclect, mas nao consegui descobri como, como poderia frazer isso?

ja tentei:

```
 var xx = document.getElementById('selectize_fornecedor').value;
```

porem nao dá certo

Comment: é fornecedor ou medicamento ? porque o seu JS está escrito medicamento e no seu html é fornecedor. Mas o que vai fazer você pegar o valor correto é o seu ng-model, que no seu caso é: $scope.objFornecedor.selectedFornecedor;

Comment: nesse caso ai Hugo, ele pega o id, mas eu preciso pegar o do texto que aparece na caixa

Comment: Cara, neste selectize você vai ter que fazer gambiarra... Não achei outra forma de te ajudar a não ser assim. Dentro do seu options(itemsMedicamento) você coloca um onChange assim:   onChange:function(v){alert(document.querySelectorAll('[data-value='+v+']')[0].outerText);}

Answer (score 0):

Partindo do princípio que sua estrutura HTML é essa, é possível obter o texto de um nó anterior usando [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling).

**Exemplo:**

```js
var label = document.getElementById("selectize_fornecedor").previousElementSibling;
console.log(label.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
  <label>Fornecedor</label>
  <selectize  id="selectize_fornecedor"></selectize >
</div>
```

Comment: mas nesse caso, ele esta pegando o texto da label certo, eu quero pegar o texto q foi selecionado no select

Comment: sim, sao todos options